# Add function to kivy screen

Tags: python, kivy

When I leave the mainscreen for the first time, the screen is duplicated. When I return to mainscreen for the first time, the screen is all black. But then it works fine.

The image of the second screen the first time I swipe [image].
The mainscreen image the first time I come back: [image]. But then it works fine for the second and other swipe.

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Go to main screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
        Button:
            text: 'Go to second screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
<MainScreen>:
    # add Game widget
    Game:
        power: powerbar
        lifes: lifesbar
        id: game
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Go to the menu screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
    FloatLayout:
        ShootProgressBar:
            id: powerbar
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.035, 'y': 0.9}
            size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
            max:10
        LifesProgressBar:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            id: lifesbar
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.7, 'y': 0.92}
            size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
            max:3
            value:3
        Image:
            id: ethereum
            size_hint: (0.04, 0.04)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.002, 'y': 0.93}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "ethereum.png"
        Image:
            id: lifes_img
            size_hint: (0.04, 0.04)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.952, 'y': 0.93}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "lifes.png"

<SecondScreen>:
    # add Game widget
    Game:
        power: powerbar
        lifes: lifesbar
        id: game
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
    FloatLayout:
        ShootProgressBar:
            id: powerbar
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.035, 'y': 0.9}
            size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
            max:10
        LifesProgressBar:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            id: lifesbar
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.7, 'y': 0.92}
            size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
            max:3
            value:3
        Image:
            id: ethereum
            size_hint: (0.04, 0.04)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.002, 'y': 0.93}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "ethereum.png"
        Image:
            id: lifes_img
            size_hint: (0.04, 0.04)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.952, 'y': 0.93}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "lifes.png"
            
<-ShootProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        BorderImage:
            border: (12, 12, 12, 12)
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - 3
            size: self.width, 24
            source : 'black_bg.png'
        BorderImage:
            border: [int(min(self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 12))] * 4
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - 12
            size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 24
            source : 'blue_fg.png'
            
<-LifesProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        BorderImage:
            border: (12, 12, 12, 12)
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - 14
            size: self.width, 24
            source: 'black_bg.png'
        BorderImage:
            border: [int(min(self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 12))] * 4
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - 12
            size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 24
            source: 'green2_fg.png'

<ColourScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'colour {:.2},{:.2},{:.2} screen'.format(*root.colour[:3])
            font_size: 30
        Widget:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.colour
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'goto first screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.new_colour_screen()
""")


# Declare both screens

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.game.initialize()
        self.ids.game.power.value = 0
        self.ids.game.lifes.value = 3
        self.update_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.game.update_glsl, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.update_event.cancel()
        self.ids.game.indices = []
        self.ids.game.vertices = []
        self.ids.game.particles = []
        self.ids.game.canvas.clear()
        self.update_event = None
            


class SecondScreen(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.game.initialize()
        self.ids.game.power.value = 0
        self.ids.game.lifes.value = 3
        self.update_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.game.update_glsl, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.update_event.cancel()
        self.ids.game.indices = []
        self.ids.game.vertices = []
        self.ids.game.particles = []
        self.ids.game.canvas.clear()
        self.update_event = None
```

What I want is to use conditions to change the screen. For example, `if self.parent.power.value == 10: sm.current = 'second'`

Comment: What functions are not working? Where is your code that is supposed to do the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you can add your `Game` widget to the `MainScreen` in the `kv` (you must also adjust the size of the `Button` so that it does not cover the entire `MainScreen`):

```
<MainScreen>:
    # add Game widget
    Game:
        id: game
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Go to the second screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
    FloatLayout:
        ShootProgressBar:
            id: powerbar
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.035, 'y': 0.9}
            size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
            max:10
        LifesProgressBar:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            id: lifesbar
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.7, 'y': 0.92}
            size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
            max:3
            value:3
        Image:
            id: ethereum
            size_hint: (0.04, 0.04)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.002, 'y': 0.93}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "ethereum.png"
        Image:
            id: lifes_img
            size_hint: (0.04, 0.04)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.952, 'y': 0.93}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "lifes.png"
```

Then in the `MainScreen` and `SecondSceen` classes, you can do the initialize and start the updating:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.game.initialize()
        self.ids.game.power.value = 0
        self.ids.game.lifes.value = 0
        self.update_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.game.update_glsl, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.update_event.cancel()
        self.ids.game.indices = []
        self.ids.game.vertices = []
        self.ids.game.particles = []
        self.ids.game.canvas.clear()
        self.update_event = None


class SecondScreen(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.game1.initialize()
        self.ids.game1.power.value = 0
        self.ids.game1.lifes.value = 0
        self.update_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.game1.update_glsl, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.update_event.cancel()
        self.ids.game1.indices = []
        self.ids.game1.vertices = []
        self.ids.game1.particles = []
        self.ids.game1.canvas.clear()
        self.update_event = None
```

and in the `Game.update_glsl()` method, use `super` to access the `PSWidget` update method, like this:

```
def update_glsl(self, nap):
    if self.use_mouse:
        self.player_x, self.player_y = Window.mouse_pos

    if self.firing:
        self.fire_delay -= nap

    self.spawn_delay -= nap

    super(Game, self).update_glsl(nap)
```

Also. in your `PSWidget` class, change the definition of `indices`, `vertices`, and `particles` to make them `Properties`, like this:

```
class PSWidget(Widget):
    indices = ListProperty([])
    vertices = ListProperty([])
    particles = ListProperty([])
```

Comment: Using your code and my modifications, the stars and enemies appear when I run it.

Comment: I applied the example, this is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4UwT.png
Here is the code I applied: https://pastebin.com/VpDKFjia

Comment: Can you share an example of full code with your solution? I'm really blocked

Comment: In the code that you posted in pastebin, most of your classes are duplicated and defined as nested classes inside your `Screen` classes. As a result, that code won't work. Also, in my answer, I said to add the `on_enter()` method to the `MainScreen` class, but you added it to one of the now two `Game` classes in your code. My version of your code is [here](https://pastebin.com/LWDaCFRx), but some is commented out since I didn't have some images or audio files that you used.

Comment: By the way, you do not need the `Game1` class, since you never use it, and it is just a duplicate of `Game`.

Comment: I updated the question. I'm sorry, but I still can't do it.

Comment: Try the latest change to my answer.